# List of same type of embedded objects in 2 different objects

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-embedded-object

I had a relationship pattern in coredata, which I am trying to migrate to realm but doubt whether the same pattern can be established here..

```
class GrandParent: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) public var primaryId: ObjectId
    @Persisted public var name: String
    @Persisted public var dob: String
    @Persisted public var children: List<Parent>
    @Persisted public var grandChildren: List<Child>
}

class Parent: EmbeddedObject {
    @Persisted public var name: String
    @Persisted public var dob: String
    @Persisted public var children: List<Child>
    @Persisted(originProperty: "children") public var parents: LinkingObjects<GrandParent>
}

class Child: EmbeddedObject {
    @Persisted public var name: String
    @Persisted public var dob: String
    @Persisted(originProperty: "grandChildren") public var grandParents: LinkingObjects<GrandParent>
}
```

I used this kinda pattern so that I dont need to loop through the Parent objects each time I want to know the grandchildren of the grandparents.
As the realm documentation reads,
*'An embedded object exists as nested data inside of a **single, specific parent object**.'*,

Is it possible to have List of Child inside both GrandParent and Parent classes ?

1. If possible, will it cascade delete the List of Child when either of GrandParent or Parent is deleted ?
2. If it is **not** possible, what is the proper way to achieve such pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded objects are 'part' of the parent object and do not exist outside of that object.

So, yes to 1), deleting a Grandparent would also delete Parent and Child objects in it's lists. From the docs

> An embedded object exists as nested data inside of a single, specific
> parent object. It inherits the lifecycle of its parent object and
> cannot exist as an independent Realm object. Realm automatically
> deletes embedded objects if their parent object is deleted or when
> overwritten by a new embedded object instance.
>
> Realm Uses Cascading Deletes for Embedded Objects When you delete a
> Realm object, any embedded objects referenced by that object are
> deleted with it.

One potential issue here is there is no back-relationship from a child to their parent - from the GrandParent List property. In other words, if you get a grandparents grandkids, you won't know who their parents are.

Something to keep in mind is that Embedded objects cannot be queried separately; they have to be queried through the parent object via dot notation. So adding LinkingObjects to an embedded object may have no function since you have to know the parent object to get to those anyway.

I suggest making Parent and Child objects managed, and access the grandkids through their grandparent->parent

```
class GrandParent: Object {
    @Persisted public var children: List<Parent>
}

class Parent: Object {
    @Persisted public var children: List<Child>
    @Persisted(originProperty: "children"( var parents: LinkingObjects<GrandParent>
}

class Child: Object {
    @Persisted(originProperty: "children") var parents: LinkingObjects<Parent>
}
```

You may even want to consider a single class to handle it all, something like this:

```
class Person: Object {
    @Persisted var type: PersonTypeEnum //grandparent, parent, child
    @Persisted public var children: List<Person>
}
```